# make infinite scroll in vanilla/pure JS without creating gap

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, scrollview, infinite-scroll

when one cycle is complete then you can see the gap.. I want to get rid of it.
it will re-cycle one after another without creating gap.

would anyone can give me some times to resolve this..

```js
const scrollAnimation = (function() {
  let element = null;
  // let obejct = {};
  let scroller = true;
  let scrollSpeed = 0;
  let parentElement = null;
  let childElement = null;
  let viewHeight = 0;

  const toggleScrollEvent = function(e) {
    scroller = (e.type == 'mouseenter') ? false : true;
  }


  const setProperty = function(element, obejct) {

    viewHeight = document.querySelector(element).clientHeight

    scrollSpeed = obejct.scrollSpeed;

    // create child element 
    childElement = document.createElement('div');
    childElement.id = 'childElement';

    // append scroll content to  child element 
    let items = document.querySelectorAll(element + ' .item');
    items.forEach(function(item) {
      childElement.appendChild(item)
    });

    // append child element to parent element
    element = document.querySelector(element);
    parentElement = element.appendChild(childElement)

    // set child element top property value manually 200px
    // let hg = childElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    childElement.style.top = viewHeight + 'px';



    parentElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', toggleScrollEvent);
    parentElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', toggleScrollEvent);

  }

  const scrollEelement = function() {
    let posY = parseInt(childElement.style.top);
    if (scroller) {
      if (posY + childElement.clientHeight > 0) {
        childElement.style.top = posY - scrollSpeed + 'px'
      } else {
        childElement.style.top = viewHeight + 'px';
      }
    }
  }

  setInterval(scrollEelement, 50)



  return {
    init: function(element, obejct) {
      setProperty(element, obejct)
    }
  }

})([]);

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  scrollAnimation.init('#parentElement', {
    scrollSpeed: 5,
  });
})
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#parentElement {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid royalblue;
}

#parentElement #childElement {
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentElement">
  <h1 class="item">Start</h1>
  <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
  <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
  <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
  <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
  <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
  <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
  <h1 class="item" style="background: orangered;">End</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scrollEelement function, where you check if you need to restart the scroll, you can check if the current top position is less than the negative value of the height on one of the ".item" divs.  If it is, remove the first item from the div and append it again at the end.  As these divs have a height of 45px, as soon as the childElement div's top is less then -45, the top ".item" div is no longer visible and can be removed and replaced at the end of the div - and adjust the childElement's top to add back on the 45px for the removed item.  So:

```js
const scrollAnimation  = (function(){
      let element = null;
      // let obejct = {};
      let scroller = true;
      let scrollSpeed = 0;
      let  parentElement= null;
      let childElement = null;
      let viewHeight = 0;

      const toggleScrollEvent = function (e){
            scroller = (e.type == 'mouseenter') ? false : true;
        }
     

     const  setProperty =  function(element,obejct){

          viewHeight  = document.querySelector(element).clientHeight
       
            scrollSpeed = obejct.scrollSpeed;

            // create child element 
            childElement =  document.createElement('div');
            childElement.id = 'childElement';

           // append scroll content to  child element 
            let items = document.querySelectorAll(element+ ' .item');
            items.forEach(function(item){
              childElement.appendChild(item)
            });

            // append child element to parent element
            element = document.querySelector(element);
            parentElement = element.appendChild(childElement)

            // set child element top property value manually 200px
            // let hg = childElement.getBoundingClientRect();
            childElement.style.top = viewHeight+ 'px';


            
            parentElement.addEventListener('mouseenter',toggleScrollEvent);
            parentElement.addEventListener('mouseleave',toggleScrollEvent);

      } 


    const scrollEelement = function(){
      let posY = parseInt(childElement.style.top);
      // Get the first child div
      let firstDiv = childElement.querySelectorAll(".item")[0];
      // Check its height
      let firstDivHeight = firstDiv.clientHeight;
      // If we are scrolling...
      if(scroller){
        // Find out where the scroll would move to
        let tmppos = posY - scrollSpeed;
        // If it is higher than the height of the first div
        if (tmppos < 0 - firstDivHeight) {
          // remove the first div
          childElement.removeChild(firstDiv);
          // .. and append it to the end
          childElement.appendChild(firstDiv);
          // .. and do the scroll
          childElement.style.top = (tmppos + firstDivHeight) + "px";
        } else {
          // otherwise, just do the scroll
          childElement.style.top = tmppos + "px";
        }
      }
    }

   setInterval(scrollEelement,10)

    return {
      init:function(element,obejct){
       setProperty(element,obejct)
      }
    }

  })([]);

  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    scrollAnimation.init('#parentElement',{
      scrollSpeed:1,
    });
  })
```

```css
 *,*::after,*::before{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body,html{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    
      #parentElement{
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
        background: #eeeeee;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 2px solid royalblue;
      }
        #parentElement #childElement{
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id="parentElement">
      <h1 class="item">Start</h1>
      <h1 class="item">Mid................<br>..............on two lines</h1>
      <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
      <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
      <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
      <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
      <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
      <h1 class="item" style="background: orangered;">End</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: why is it flickering? (animation is not smooth)

Comment: That's down to the timing/length of the scroll.  The scroll jumps 5px every 50ms.  If I change these to 1px every 10ms (ie, 1/5th the speed but 5 times as fast), there's no flickering.

Comment: @Gad  Actually, it would also appear that the height of the ".item" divs is different in different browsers.  I've updated the Answer to set the height to 45px.

Comment: `.item` height problem ... if I put one more line content. it's not working ...

Comment: Ok - it should just be a case of finding out the height of the first div and using that instead of a fixed 45.  I'll have a look.

Comment: I have updated my Answer to check for the height of the first div and adjust based on that instead of a fixed 45px.  The css style that set the height is no longer required, so has been removed.  Also, there is no need to keep the **viewHeight** code now as the divs will continuously scroll and update their own order, so we will never need to adjust the top manually.

Comment: @ATD i can not handle speed with your code... if i change `scrollSpeed` number it's doesn't make me sense what is happens.. would review code please ......

Comment: Speed and the setInterval call are related.  Speed moves the divs up by a given number of pixels and setInterval controls how often that happens.  The original was 5px and 50ms but that produces a flickering as 5px is relatively large (it's about 1/3 of the height of a character on this page).  I've set these to 1px and 10ms to show a smooth scroll.  If you want, you could increase the setInterval value to slow things down.

Comment: sorry for disturb you.. i did not notice you changed  the   `setInterval(fun,10)` .. okay..

Comment: Sorry, I should have pointed that out - I was just trying everything to get smooth scrolling in every browser and forgot that I'd done that!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using mostly css animations.

```js
const containerElem = document.querySelector('.container');
const contentElem = document.querySelector('.content');
const contentCloneElem = contentElem.cloneNode(true);
containerElem.appendChild(contentCloneElem);

const pxPerSec = 100;
const contentHeight = contentElem.clientHeight;
containerElem.style.animationDuration = `${contentHeight / pxPerSec}s`;
```

```css
.infiniteScroll {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

@keyframes changePos {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}

.container {
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: changePos;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

.container:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Infinite Scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="infiniteScroll">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <h1 class="item">Start</h1>
        <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
        <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
        <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
        <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
        <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
        <h1 class="item">Mid</h1>
        <h1 class="item" style="background: orangered;">End</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```